# SuiteTalk invalid credentials error in LCS training

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitetalk

I'm completing training on SuiteTalk in Oracle LCS. It appears that course files are no longer compatible with training account and it takes forever to get to get instructor's answer.

I'm attempting Token-based authentication and I keep getting this error:
`SOAP FAULT: fault type=platformFaults:invalidCredentialsFault with code=.`
I disabled code which used `Passport` user credentials and enabled code which utilized `TokenPassport`. I tried both 2017_2 and 2022_1 WSDL. I can see that Token-based passport gets signed but when I execute any command against the service object I keep getting credentials error. Yer, I have reset and copied all 4 strings used to create token passport and I did populate account number.

Has anyone powered through this ditch in Oracle LCS training? Can you provide any adivce?

Comment: did you get any solution? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Service object uses SHA1 algorithm. It has to be updated to SHA256 in 2 locations - as a string and as enumerable value.